# Reference an instance of a class by a property in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Given the following:

```
    class Parent {
        private String name,
        private List<Child> children
    }

    class Child {
        private String name
    }
```

I'd like to be able to refer to a specific child by using:

```
    parent.children('bob')
```

Instead of by index:

```
    parent.children[0]
```

How would this be done in Groovy?

Comment: If you are dealing with a familial structure watch out for things like: https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2014/jun/28/two-of-our-childen-have-same-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a method to `Parent` to do it:

```
Child children(String name) {
    children.find { it.name == name }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

define children as map:

```
Map<String,Child> children
```

then

```
parent.children.bob
```

or

```
parent.children[ 'bob' ]
```

Comment: How does the initial declaration of children "know" that I'm looking for the property "name" and not some other property in the class?

Comment: You must put the values into the map keyed by name property: 'parent.children[ child.name ] = child'